# create layout in xamrin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to create a header layout for one my activity like below image.
I have tried but couldn't do that.
Can anyone help me for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml file inside a **RelativeLayout**:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="my text under image"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

TextView and ImageView must be included inside a RelativeLayout so the layout_below to be valid.